# Register a COM dll in the GAC with WiX

Tags: c#, wix, gac, custom-action, regasm

Greetings all,

I'm working on a WiX installation script for my program.  I need to install a C# dll to the GAC and then register it.  So, I mark the file with `Assembly=".net"` so that WiX GACs it for me, and then I have a deferred custom action, set to run before `InstallFinalize`, which calls `Assembly.Load` to load the assembly from the GAC and then `RegistrationServices.RegisterAssembly` to register it.

Should be perfect, except for one problem: Apparently the dll isn't actually written to the GAC until the commit phase, so when my custom action runs, `Assembly.Load` throws because it can't find the file.  Where is it?  Is it at all accessible before the commit phase?  Or is there a better way to do this entirely?  Seems like such a trivial thing...

Please do not suggest using `heat.exe`; I'd really like to avoid it.  My program has a `ComRegisterFunction` that would like to execute on the user's computer if at all possible.

Comment: Did you ever find the solution? stuck with the exact same issue :(

Answer (score 0):

Self-registration in general is frowned upon during installation, exactly because of problems like the one you described. You should add the registry entries to the WiX script instead.

Also, you are not installing your assembly in the GAC only, are you? Point your COM registration to the non-GAC location.

Comment: I *am* installing to the GAC only, that's precisely the problem.  I'm asking if it stores it in some temp location first, somewhere that I can access with my custom action.  I know self-registration is looked down upon, but I don't like losing the opportunity to run conditional checks upon registration.  Plus, heat.exe shows that my registry entries are very large, one entry for each class in my program.  I don't know if they're all necessary or what, but that's going to be constantly changing.  I really don't want to have to update it constantly...

Comment: What I meant was "do not install in the GAC only, install in a well-known location for your product as well". :-) Yes, the assemblies are unpacked in a temporary folder during installation, but if you run your COM registration from that folder, the CLR will look for them in it, when used through COM, due to the Codepath reg value pointing there.

Comment: Also, you should really expose to COM only the classes you need, by applying ComVisible to these directly, instead of to the whole assembly. And, to avoid constantly changing reg entries, apply explicit GUIDs to your COM-visible classes and interfaces, instead of letting the compiler regenerate those every time. (Besides, for backward compatibility, you _will_ have to freeze the GUIDs after you ship your first version)

Comment: Okay, but do I *want* the CLR looking for my DLL in the well-known location?  Won't that cause some problems when it tries to load it from the GAC as well?  Also, I am only apply ComVisible to a view classes, and they do have GUIDs assigned.  But for whatever reason it seems that regasm wants to write something to the registry about my every class, even the ones I haven't tagged.

Comment: Check if you have an assembly:ComVisible attribute anywhere in your sources.

Comment: I specifically have assembly:ComVisible(false)

Comment: Yes, you want the CLR looking for your assembly at the well-known location, when activated through COM. (Well, if you ask me - you never want your assembly in the GAC, but that's a separate story :-)) No, that shouldn't pose problems, as the assembly loading is controlled by the assembly identity, which should be the same between the two copies in the GAC and your location.

Comment: Hm, that's strange. Only classes and interfaces that are marked as ComVisible should be registered for COM. Can you open the assembly with Reflector or ildasm and verify it doesn't have the ComVisible(true) at assembly level?

Comment: This answer is not helpful - while OP's thing can certainly worked around with copying file to two locations and then registering, i, for one, am installing a windows component that has to be registered in gac coz windows powershell looks only there, so i do need to call this in the same manner.

Comment: Are you saying PowerShell is looking in the COM registry to determine the location of the COM component, but then ignoring the path to it, and looking in the GAC? If that's the case, it should still work, if you have both copies.

Or are you saying PowerShell is looking at the COM registration, and if the path is not in the GAC, it refuses to load the assembly at all? This sounds to me like a ... strange decision by the PowerShell team.

Disclaimer: This answer was written seven years ago. Things might have changed since. Feel free to update it, if you have more current information.

Comment: @FranciPenov I am saying that i'm installing an ADFS extension and it is a pre-requisite as per MSDN guides for the assembly to be present in GAC. E.g. it is not a powershell specific problem in my case, but the cmdlet i'm invoking.

Comment: @zaitsman fair enough. However, what I was trying to explain is that you can have the assembly in the GAC, but you don't have to do COM registration from the GAC. You can have the assembly in another place in addition to having in the GAC< and you can run the COM registration from that place. The CoCIEx will hand off the assembly loading to the CLR, and it will still load it from the GAC as long as the identity of the two copies is the same. You will run into problems if you upgrade one of the two at later point but don't upgrade the other, but if you keep them in sync, it should work.